# Synapse "The specified option 'Ole Automation Procedures' is not supported by this edition of SQL Server and cannot be changed using sp_configure."

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-synapse

I try to run a stored procedure. It includes:
...
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options',1
reconfigure with override
exec sp_configure 'ole automation procedures',1
reconfigure with override
....

When I copied and pasted it to Synapse, it didn't work. What function or solution should I use instead of it?[image]
[image]

to run the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/ole-automation-procedures-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16) Currently **`Ole Automation Procedures`** Server Configuration Options are **only supported in SQL server** not in Azure synapse Analytics.

[image]

You can raise the feature request for that [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/9b9ba8e4-0825-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8).